# grep emails from SMTP mail.log

Tags: regex, grep

Let's say i have a textfile from a smtp log (like below), what is the regex for grep to extract the emails in this log file?

```
Jun  4 17:19:12 username postfix/pickup[22643]: C92866601: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Jun  4 17:19:12 username postfix/cleanup[23012]: C92866601: message-id=<20120604151912.C92866601@username.website.com>
Jun  4 17:19:12 username postfix/qmgr[2591]: C92866601: from=<www-data@email.com>, size=1314, nrcpt=2 (queue active)
Jun  4 17:19:13 username postfix/smtp[23014]: C92866601: to=<foobar@gmail.com>, relay=smtp.domain.com[134.96.7.25]:25, delay=0.5, delays=0.132, delays=11/0.01/0.09/0.21, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 q53M4Dg6001057 Message accepted for delivery)
Jun  4 17:19:13 username postfix/smtp[23014]: C92866601: to=<mail-user@domain.com>, relay=smtp.domain.com[134.96.7.25]:25, delay=0.5, delays=0.132, delays=11/0.01/0.09/0.21, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 q53M4Dg6001057 Message accepted for delivery)
Jun  4 17:19:13 username postfix/qmgr[2591]: C92866601: removed
Jun  4 17:19:13 username postfix/pickup[22643]: E146B6601: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Jun  4 17:19:13 username postfix/cleanup[23012]: E146B6601: message-id=<20120604151913.E146B6601@username.website.com>
Jun  4 17:19:13 username postfix/qmgr[2591]: E146B6601: from=<www-data@email.com>, size=1327, nrcpt=2 (queue active)
Jun  4 17:19:14 username postfix/smtp[23014]: E146B6601: to=<mail-user@domain.com>, relay=smtp.domain.com[134.96.7.31]:25, delay=0.43, delays=0.132, delays=11/0.01/0.09/0.21, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 q53M4Dg6001057 Message accepted for delivery)
Jun  4 17:19:14 username postfix/smtp[23014]: E146B6601: to=<barbar@gmail.com>, relay=smtp.domain.com[134.96.7.31]:25, delay=0.43, delays=0.132, delays=11/0.01/0.09/0.21, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 q53M4Dg6001057 Message accepted for delivery)
Jun  4 17:19:14 username postfix/qmgr[2591]: E146B6601: removed
Jun  4 17:19:14 username postfix/pickup[22643]: EF1606601: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Jun  4 17:19:14 username postfix/cleanup[23012]: EF1606601: message-id=<20120604151914.EF1606601@username.website.com>
Jun  4 17:19:15 username postfix/qmgr[2591]: EF1606601: from=<www-data@email.com>, size=1329, nrcpt=2 (queue active)
Jun  4 17:19:15 username postfix/smtp[23014]: EF1606601: to=<mail-user@domain.com>, relay=smtp.domain.com[134.96.7.31]:25, delay=0.42, delays=0.132, delays=11/0.01/0.09/0.21, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 q53M4Dg6001057 Message accepted for delivery)
Jun  4 17:19:15 username postfix/smtp[23014]: EF1606601: to=<foofoo@gmail.com>, relay=smtp.domain.com[134.96.7.31]:25, delay=0.42, delays=0.132, delays=11/0.01/0.09/0.21, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 q53M4Dg6001057 Message accepted for delivery)
Jun  4 17:19:15 username postfix/qmgr[2591]: EF1606601: removed
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 grep -o '[-a-zA-Z0-9.]*@.[^>]*' filename
```

I considered alphabets, numbers, hyphen and dot as valid email name.

If you are unsure about the email name convention used in log file, then try this:

```
grep -o '<[^@]*@.[^>]*' filename
```

The above command gives emails prepend with `<`.